# Database in transition

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that has been locked in transition for over 24 hours.  I found a similar thread that discusses how to find the commands that are running but I do not know how to unlock the database.  **How can I resolve this transition state?**

Query to get currently running commands:

```
use _MYDB_
go

select
    l.resource_type,
    l.request_mode,
    l.request_status,
    l.request_session_id,
    r.command,
    r.status,
    r.blocking_session_id,
    r.wait_type,
    r.wait_time,
    r.wait_resource,
    request_sql_text = st.text,
    s.program_name,
    most_recent_sql_text = stc.text
from sys.dm_tran_locks l
left join sys.dm_exec_requests r
on l.request_session_id = r.session_id
left join sys.dm_exec_sessions s
on l.request_session_id = s.session_id
left join sys.dm_exec_connections c
on s.session_id = c.session_id
outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) st
outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) stc
where l.resource_database_id = db_id('_MYDB_')
order by request_session_id;
```

**Results:**
[image: Results from the query:]

Comment: You were trying to take database offline and it is blocked by 53 so its stuck there. If you want to remove transition you would have to kill spid 53 or will have to wait it to finish.

Comment: When I try to kill it I still get the transition error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Attempting to kill the offending process failed with the same error.  In the end I had to reboot the server to get by the issue.

Comment: It seems like your issue was related to xp_fixeddrives.  I've had all kinds of blocking/hanging issues with xp's in SQL Server that try to work with the disk.  Sometimes if the underlying process in Windows is killed SQL might have an issue, or vice versa.  Since enabling xp's can be dangerous and make it harder to pass an audit, I'd recommend using this to get more info than the xp provides and it's safer:http://tomaslind.net/2014/01/28/alternative-xp_fixeddrives/